# how to create transition from selection (importing d3-selection module)

Tags: d3.js

The new [selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection) module doesn't seem to depend on [transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) module.

How do I properly create transition from existing selection? Doing the old way `selection.transition()` doesn't work, as new Selection doesn't have `.transition()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to edit the question to give more details I've found an answer. Digging into the [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/src/selection/index.js) made the solution obvious:

```
import { } from "d3-transition/src/selection";
```

it simply adds `transition` method to the `selection.prototype`.